# MyBatis Populate List<?> field in POJO object from multiple return columns

Tags: java, sql, list, mapping, mybatis

I am using MyBatis and want to populate a List field in my resulting POJO object based on multiple returned columns.

For example, my resulting POJO looks like this:

```
public class Garage {
    public List<Car> cars
}
```

where Car instance defined:

```
public class Car {
    public String name;
    public Integer year;
}
```

So running an SQL statement on my example database:

```
SELECT
    sc.name AS "speedy_car_name"
    sc.year AS "speedy_car_year"
    bc.name AS "default_car_name"
    bc.year AS "default_car_year"
FROM sport_cars sc
    JOIN basic_cars bc ON sc.year = bc.year
WHERE year = 2017;
```

Will give me as a result:

```
porsche, 2017, prius, 2017
```

Is it possible to instantinate entries in List object based on multiple column returned by SQL statement? For example, like this (just an example not working mapping):

```
<select id="getMyCars" resultMap="garageTypeMap"
SELECT
    sc.name AS "speedy_car_name"
    sc.year AS "speedy_car_year"
    bc.name AS "default_car_name"
    bc.year AS "default_car_year"
FROM sport_cars sc
    JOIN basic_cars bc ON sc.year = bc.year
WHERE year = 2017;
</select>

<resultMap id="garageTypeMap" type="Garage">
  <collection property="cars" ofType="Car">
    <collection property="car">
        <result property="name" column="speedy_car_name"/>
        <result property="year" column="speedy_car_year"/>
    </collection>
    <collection property="car">
        <result property="name" column="default_car_name"/>
        <result property="year" column="default_car_year"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

I tried to find anything about it here: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html (collections and associations), but could not come up with an answer to my question. Is it possible? Or do I need to refactor my classes a little? (database structure cannot be touched).

Comment: So there will always going to be two set of Car entries? How about creating two separate lists?

Comment: on my real data I am always getting two fields that describes same entity type, but they gathered from different tables based on some common parameter, and I want to map it to this one object with collection field inside of it. I am thinking of adding extra two fields on Garage object with getters\setters that will create Car and add it to the list field, but it does not look like a good approach.